# multiple cells selected on scrolling [reuse cells problem]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a collectionViewCell which contains an image and a label. When I select a cell and scroll ahead I find other cell being selected. Also when I scroll back I find the other cell and not the cell I selected is selected.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return followedUsers.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = attachProfilesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "attachCells", for: indexPath) as? attachUsersCell
    cell!.subscribedUserId = self.followedUsers[indexPath.row].userId
    cell?.profileNameToAttah.text = self.followedUsers[indexPath.row].fullName
    cell?.profileImageToAttch.loadImagesWithUrl(from: self.followedUsers[indexPath.row].ImagePath)



    if mLastSelectedIndex == indexPath.row {
    cell?.isSelected = true}
    else{cell?.isSelected = false}

    return cell!
}




func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 80, height: 110)
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         let cell = attachProfilesCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! attachUsersCell
                cell.subscribedUserId = following[indexPath.item]
                usersToAttach.append(cell.subscribedUserId)
                attachedCounter += 1
                attachCounterFun()
                print(usersToAttach)
    cell.checkMarkImage.isHidden = false
    attachCounterFun()
    guard mLastSelectedIndex != indexPath.row else{return}
    mLastSelectedIndex = indexPath.row
    print("this is  addition \(usersToAttach)")
}




func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  let cell_ = attachProfilesCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! attachUsersCell
    let toRemove = usersToAttach.index(of: following[indexPath.row])
    usersToAttach.remove(at: toRemove!)
    attachedCounter -= 1
     attachCounterFun()
    print(usersToAttach)
    cell_.checkMarkImage.isHidden = true
    print("this is removal \(usersToAttach)")
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if isSelected {
        cell.isSelected = true}
    else { isSelected = false }
}
```

At present I have enabled paging and almost there but occasionally the selected cells change selection upon scroll

Comment: Please share the code in `cellForItem`

Comment: Cells are reused. Handle it properly. And **never** manipulate a cell outside of `cellForItem` without updating the data model.

Comment: @koen updated that in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain global variable in your controller

```
var mLastSelectedIndex = -1
```

Whenever cellForRowAtIndexPath method called check if current cell is selected or not .If this is selected One update its UI. I suggest you to change selected cell UI on cell class only. This way you can easily manage cell tapping and helps you writing clean code.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = attachProfilesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "attachCells", for: indexPath) as? attachUsersCell
  cell!.subscribedUserId = self.followedUsers[indexPath.row].userId
  cell?.profileNameToAttah.text = self.followedUsers[indexPath.row].fullName
  cell?.profileImageToAttch.loadImagesWithUrl(from:   self.followedUsers[indexPath.row].ImagePath)
// here update selected index path
  if mLastSelectedIndex == indexPath.row {
      cell?.isSelected = true
  }
else{ 
    cell?.isSelected = false
  }

   return cell!
}
```

Update last selected index on cell tapped.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    guard mLastSelectedIndex != IndexPath.row else{return}
    let indexpath = IndexPath(row:mLastSelectedIndex, section: 0)
    mColllectionView.cellForItem(at: indexpath)?.isSelected = !mColllectionView.cellForItem(at: indexpath)!.isSelected
    mLastSelectedIndex = IndexPath.row 
  }
```

In your **attachUsersCell.swift** declare *isSelected* property of cell  . The default value of this property is false, which indicates that the cell is not selected.

```
override var isSelected: Bool{
    didSet{
        if isSelected {

          setSelectedUI()

        }
        else{

            setUnSelectedUI()

        }

    }
}

func setSelectedUI(){
     borderColor = UIColor.systemOrange
     borderWidth = 2
     cornerRadius = 8
      clipsToBounds = true
}

func setUnSelectedUI(){
    // reset to default ui
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: great help  but still while I scroll across and then back, i find my selected cell indicators missing. Still trying figure out the problem

Comment: did you try above approach ? whenever you scroll up or down cell is created or reused and cell properties are being filled provided by your datasource in cellforrowatindex method . you have to make sure datasource[indexpath.row]  provide right data , wether it is selected or not  . if you follow this properly your problem will resolve .

Comment: i tried your approach and was successful a bit, now the cells are being selected properly but when i scroll horizontally to and fro I see changes in some of my selections, they become un selected but when i force scroll it again everything goes normal. I have enabled paging to fix that problem for now , but paging wasn't desired

Comment: can you change your 'did select' method , I've made some changes .

Comment: It only worsens buddy, still the same results, I can provide you with more code if you want

Comment: give it upvote :p , it gives motivation to write more .

Comment: can't do that i have less than 15 reputations :(