# How to override init an UITableViewCell with variable?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So, I have an `UITableViewCell` that has an `Bool` variable and I need to initialize it with a value. But I can't attribute it in the class, because it gets reloaded and it override the passing value at `didSelectRowAt` table method.

This is my cell:

```
class DropDownTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var icon: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var isOpenned: Bool

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.selectionStyle = .none
}

func removesIcon() {
    self.icon.image = nil
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

func changeSelectedCell(_ selected: Bool) {
    if selected {
        self.icon.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "VectorUp")
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
    } else {
        self.icon.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "VectorDown")
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = 16
    }
}
```

And these are my tableview methods

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let collapsed = selectedIndex == indexPath.section ? false : true

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as? DropDownTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("There should be a cell with \(identifier) identifier.")
        }
        cell.titleLabel.text = newModules[indexPath.section].sectionData
        cell.icon.rotate(collapsed ? (2 * .pi) : .pi * 3)

        if newModules[indexPath.section].section.isEmpty {
            cell.removesIcon()
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: subIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? DropDownSubTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("There should be a cell with \(identifier) identifier.")
        }
        cell.label.text = newModules[indexPath.section].section[indexPath.row - 1]
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if newModules[indexPath.section].section.isEmpty {
        coordinator?.goToSubModule(subModules: parents[indexPath.section])
    } else {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            if newModules[indexPath.section].isOpenned {
                newModules[indexPath.section].isOpenned = false
                let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
                tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .automatic)
            } else {
                newModules[indexPath.section].isOpenned = true
                let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
                tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .automatic)
                selectedIndex = indexPath.section
            }
        } else {
            if parents.isEmpty {
                coordinator?.goToSubModule(subModules: ((content?.sons[indexPath.row - 1])!))
            } else {
                coordinator?.goToSubModule(subModules: parents[indexPath.section].sons[indexPath.row - 1])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see `tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .automatic`) returns it to theprevious state. So I can't just say `cell.isOpenned = true` or something like that.

Comment: You have to track your opened cells in the view controller and pass your `isOpened` to every cell each time in `cellForRow`.

Comment: it gets reset by tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .automatic)

Answer (score 0):

You need indexpath of last opened variable as int  not bool . Follow this below approach it works fine in your case as well .

[multiple cells selected on scrolling [reuse cells problem]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59293617/multiple-cells-selected-on-scrolling-reuse-cells-problem/59310052#59310052)