# How to maintain state of collection view cell after dismissal of view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So I have a collectionView that holds an array of trends users can click to feature that photo. When the cell is clicked, a checkmark appears letting the user know they have selected that category and their photoId is then entered into the selected childValues in the database.

Users have the option to edit their photo if they decided they want to remove their photo from a certain category. When I select edit profile, the cells that should be selected (ones I choose while uploading the photo) are unselected.

Or lets say for example, I already have a photo uploaded but now I want to feature it, when I go to edit photo and tap on a category the checkmark appears telling me this category is chosen. When I press save the photo is added to the chosen childValue in the database as expected, but when I click edit profile again and the view is presented. The cells I choose 10 seconds ago are now unselected.

How can I maintain a selected or deselected state even after dismissing the view controller?

```swift
   var selectedCategoryValues = [String]()
   var trend: Trend!
  var selectedIndex = -1

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

if collectionView == trendCollectionView {


let trendsCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 

"trendsCell", for: indexPath) as! TrendsCollectionCell

trendsCell.layer.cornerRadius = 9.0

trendsCell.layer.borderWidth = 0.1

trendsCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor


 if selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
            trendsCell.isSelected = true
             } else {

            trendsCell.isSelected = false

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

            if collectionView == trendCollectionView {

     guard selectedIndex != indexPath.row else{return}
     let indexpath = IndexPath(row:selectedIndex, section: 0)
     trendCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexpath)?.isSelected = !trendCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexpath)!.isSelected


        switch selectedSegmentIndex {

        case 0: self.trend = femaleTrends[indexPath.row]
        print("You selected  \(trend.childValue)")
        self.selectedCategoryValues.append(trend.childValue)




        case 1: self.trend = maleTrends[indexPath.row]
            print("You selected  \(trend.childValue)")
            self.selectedCategoryValues.append(trend.childValue)


             default: break

        }
```

Collection View Cell

```swift
class TrendsCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    override var isSelected: Bool{
        didSet{
            if isSelected {

              setSelectedUI()

            }
            else{

                setUnSelectedUI()

            }

        }
    }

    func setSelectedUI(){

    trendCheckmark.isHidden = false
    trendCheckmark.tintColor = .white

    }

    func setUnSelectedUI(){
        // reset to deafault, hide checkmark
        trendCheckmark.isHidden = true

    }

}
```

Comment: show your cell For item at indexPath too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the selected index as part of some state and then store / use that state as you wish. You'd do this by having some property `selectedIndex`, or, if you have more properties, you could have some struct `viewState` that you update in `didSelectItemAt`. You then either have some state manager outside of your view controllers (recommended) or you pass the state between view controllers (if you have a simple app).

Comment: Although every answer was pretty much the same you answered first. Thank you very much, this ended up working.

Answer (score 0):

Three needed steps for maintaining selected state of cell . This applicable for `table view` and `collection view`

**1.** Maintain last selected index for as selected cell .

**2.** Update `cellindex` on every did select call .

**3.** For every `cellforrowindex` method check if this `selected` cell or not.

Further explanation is on my previous answer
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59293617/multiple-cells-selected-on-scrolling-reuse-cells-problem/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59293617/multiple-cells-selected-on-scrolling-reuse-cells-problem/59310052#59310052)

Answer (score 0):

I never recommend using cell selected variable to detect cell selection because that variable is not completely describe the state ,  because of the dequeuing and recycling mechanism that work for UICollectionView and UITableView So I recommend Every time to rely all the state to your models ,
so you have 2 options

1. add an isSelcted property to every cell ModelObject
2. add Single property to your view Controller that reserve the selected Index

import Foundation

```
 class NumberCountDataSource: NSObject , UICollectionViewDataSource {
        let selectionAction: ((Int)->())
        let numbersCount: Int
        var selectedIndex: Int?
        init(cardsCount: Int,selectionAction: @escaping ((Int)->())) {
            self.numbersCount = cardsCount
            self.selectionAction = selectionAction

        }
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return  numbersCount
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: NumberCollectionViewCell.identiefier, for: indexPath) as! NumberCollectionViewCell
            cell.configure(number: indexPath.row + 1, isSelected: indexPath.row == selectedIndex)
            return cell
        }

    }

extension NumberCountDataSource: UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            selectedIndex = indexPath.row
            self.selectionAction(indexPath.row)
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return CGFloat.init(0.0)
        }
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return CGFloat.init(0.0)
        }
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize.init(width: 60, height: 50)
        }
    }
```

class NumberCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var numberLable: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var backGroundview: AnimatableView!
static let identiefier: String = "NumberCollectionViewCell"
static let nibName: String =  "NumberCollectionViewCell"
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
override var isSelected: Bool {
    didSet {

        setupSelection(iseSelected: isSelected)
}
}

private func setupSelection(iseSelected: Bool) {
    backGroundview.backgroundColor = isSelected ?  UIColor("#4d8ec5") : UIColor("#ffffff")
    backGroundview.borderColor = isSelected ?  UIColor.clear : UIColor("#707070")
    numberLable.textColor = isSelected ?  UIColor("#ffffff") : UIColor("#444e53")
}
func configure(number: Int,isSelected: Bool) {
    numberLable.text = "\(number)"
    setupSelection(iseSelected: isSelected)
}
```

}

Comment: Do you mind giving me an example on how to reserve the selected index? Thats where I am stuck at

Comment: in the example I just want to display Collection of Number Cards

Comment: Sorry just having a hard time wrapping my head around this. So will I be saving an array of the selected strings and the number of the index as well? Never worked with saving the state with ```didSelect ``` so I apologize if my questions are common knowledge.

Comment: I can already display the collection of categories I want, when I select/deselect the cell, the checkmark hides and unhides as expected. When I upload the photo, the photo is also posted in the correct category I selected. However when I go to edit that photo to remove the photo from the category I selected, the checkmark ```.isHidden = true``` when it should save and keep the checkmark.